# How to find out the top window package name from the window manager or status bar

Tags: android, android-source

This is not a question about an app finding out the top window. I am modifying AOSP and need the top window information from the Status Bar `topAppWindowChanged()` function. Currently the only thing passed into this function is whether the menu button should be visible. I am looking for ways to pass the package name of the top window into the function.

The function is called from the `WindowManagerService` but I can't find the package name information there either.

Update:
I've tracked it back to `WindowManagerService::addWindow()` which calls `updateFocusedWindowLocked()` which calls `mPolicy.focusChangedLw()` which calls `updateSystemUiVisibilityLw()` which dispatches the message to the status bar service. I've added a package name to these functions but I need to get the name in addWindow which only has an `IWindow` passed it. I don't know how to get a `Context` from an `IWindow`.

Comment: I am trying to do something similar. Thanks for describing the code flow :)